# laravel hidden fields on condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database and model called Vote_actions that looks like this:

id

group_id

user_id

action_type

anonymous (boolean)

User can ask to be anonymous (that would make the boolean value to be true).If that is the case, I want to change the user_id from the returned model to -1.
Usually, there will be multiple rows that will be returned. There I don't want to use a mutator for each row in the function
Is there a way in laravel that I can do it ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a mutator function? This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: I assumed from the examples that i will have to individually get each rows attributes. 
Say i run this:
User::where(id,52)->votes_actions()->get(); 
This will return many rows. 
How do I use a mutator on this so that , if anonymous field is YES, then user_id should be -1

Comment: Laravel will automatically execute the mutator against each row. Something like this in your VoteAction model: `function getUserIdAttribute($value) { if($this->anonymous) { return -1; } else { return $value; } }`

Comment: @harvey_slash, I gave you an excellent way to do this, why don't you use it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908609/laravel-model-conditional-formatting

Comment: I didn't know it worked for collections

Answer (score 0):

as what you've said that you dont want to use the mutator for this. just set directly the user_id to -1 in your controller if anonymous before saving to DB.

Comment: thats the thing. I don't want to save it like that. I just want it to be hidden if anonymous

Comment: well, i guess the only thing left is the model `filter`